# unregistered users can login into my firebase app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have implemented a login method with password and email inputs. But even unregistred emails can log. There is an alert message saying that the email doesnt correspond to any entry in the data base, still, I get to home page:

The auth service:

```
login(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
      })
  }
```

Login Component TS:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }
  get email() { return this.loginForm.get('email') }
  get password() { return this.loginForm.get('password') }



  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.invalid)
      return;

    this.authService.login(this.email.value, this.password.value)
      .then(data => {
        let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
        this.router.navigate([returnUrl || '/home']);
        console.log(data)

      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

And HTML

```
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="email.touched && email.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">email is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
              Username or password is incorrect
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center" type="submit" style="font-weight:bold">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Is something missing? Why the user is not blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are catching the error inside `authService.login`, so it is no longer an error from the outer function's perspective and the `.then` in `onSubmit` will run even when the login failed.

Just remove the `.catch` in `authService.login` (if the alert is just for testing) or add `throw error` after the `window.alert` like this:

```js
login(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message)
        throw error // <<< Rethrow! Otherwise, the error won't make it to the outside!
      })
  }
```